Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
Im trying to learn how to clean data using MySQL.
I have a column where the value is text and want to change to date. The column has both empty fields and datetime format YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss UTC. I'm trying to update the column to date format YYYY-mm-dd with the empty fields as 0000-00-00.



before
after




2023-04-27 11:31:00 UTC
2023-04-27



0000-00-00



my query is:
UPDATE table
SET column = date(str_to_date(column, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s UTC'))
WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column != ' ';

I get Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date
But when I try
SELECT
date(str_to_date(column, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s UTC')) FROM table
WHERE column IS NOT NULL AND column !=' ';

I don't receive an error message. I do get the right date format but still with NULL for the empty fields.



before
after




2023-04-27 11:31:00 UTC
2023-04-27



NULL




So, the column is of type VARCHAR?

0000-00-00 isn't a valid date. What's wrong with NULL?

Type checks that cause warnings in SELECT statements become errors in UPDATE and INSERT statements. I'll bet you'll see the same message if you do SHOW WARNINGS; after the second query.
